# Pig Latin Translator: Starting out in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, anaconda

I am new to python programming and am trying to start off with a simple pig Latin translator. I just want to look at the first letter of each word, move it to the end, and then add "Ay" to it. I have started off a little but am having trouble joining my words
For example:

Victoria Smith

output: ictoriaVay mithSay

```
ay = "ay"
original = str(input("Enter a word: "))
word = original.lower()
first= word[0]

for word in original.split():
    if len(original)<0:
        print("Enter another name")
    else:
        new_word =word[1:] + word[:1] + ay
print(new_word.capitalize(), end= " ")
```

I am also trying to join the words back together but am confused as to how I need to print that? I tried to use the print(new_word) but kept getting only my second word. Any help would be appreciated or maybe a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the print statement inside the for loop.  Then it will run it separately for each word.